# How to import font-face with font-weight 500

Tags: css, frontend, typekit

I'm working on a site that uses some adobe fonts and I'm having trouble getting a font-weight at 500.

I've got adobe font that I'm importing like this:

```
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/<some-random-code>.css">
```

The href points to a css file that looks like this:

```
...

@font-face {
  font-family:"itc-avant-garde-gothic-pro";
  src:url("<some-url>") format("woff2"),url("<some-url>") format("woff"),url("<some-url>") 
  format("opentype");
  font-display:auto;
  font-style:normal;
  font-weight:700;
}

@font-face {
  font-family:"itc-avant-garde-gothic-pro";
  src:url("<some-url>") format("woff2"),url("<some-url>") format("woff"),url("<some-url>");
  font-display:auto;
  font-style:normal;
  font-weight:300;
}


.tk-itc-avant-garde-gothic-pro { font-family: "itc-avant-garde-gothic-pro",sans-serif; }
```

It shows font-weight 300 and 700 but not 500.

My understanding is that the browser isn't going to know how how to execute CSS code that specifies that a div has `font-weight: 500`.

And in fact, when I look at selectors with `font-weight: 500` and I bump them down to 400 via the chrome developer console, I see no change.

So how do I get the site to show the font-weight I want?

Comment: Is the 500 weight version in your kit?

Comment: It's not listed in that css file.  It should be, right?

Comment: Yes, it should – if they offer the font in that weight. You might need to explicitly select it to be included somewhere though.

Comment: Go to your kit settings in your typekit account and make sure that the 500 weight is included.

Comment: Yep.  This was the problem.  It just wasn't syncing properly, so it was never made available to the browser.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I noticed when you originally add that font to a kit, the default setting is to only include Book and Bold, but if you notice there's a view one more option that is the Medium (500 weight) typeface. You need to edit your kit/web project to include it.

You shouldn't have to worry about the loaded CSS file from Adobe as long as it is loading and includes all 3 weights. If you define classes for book, medium, and bold like so

```
<style>
.book {
    font-family: itc-avant-garde-gothic-pro, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: normal;
}
.medium {
    font-family: itc-avant-garde-gothic-pro, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-style: normal;
}
.bold {
    font-family: itc-avant-garde-gothic-pro, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: normal;
}
</style>
```

Then apply those classes to your markup, you should see 3 distinct weights.

```
<p class="book">
Nunc nec neque. Cras risus ipsum, faucibus ut, ullamcorper id, varius ac, leo. Morbi nec metus. Nullam vel sem. Etiam vitae tortor. 
</p>
<p class="medium">
Sed aliquam ultrices mauris. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc, quis gravida magna mi a libero. Vivamus consectetuer hendrerit lacus. Nunc egestas, augue at pellentesque laoreet, felis eros vehicula leo, at malesuada velit leo quis pede. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. 
</p>
<p class="bold">
Etiam vitae tortor. Fusce risus nisl, viverra et, tempor et, pretium in, sapien. Donec posuere vulputate arcu. Nullam accumsan lorem in dui. Aenean imperdiet. 
</p>
```

Comment: That's how I thought it'd work but that's not the experience I'm having.

Comment: This really doesn't answer the question, as OP states that the font weight for 500 isn't loading. This leads to the font weight not being included in the kit itself in typekit.

Comment: Sorry, I did add "as long as it [the kit] is loading and includes all 3 weights". I tried to include the entirety of the process, but I agree It's most likely the medium weight not being included in the kit.